# Meaning of なき in a sentence

Tags: word-choice

Sentence:

全員のオススメを食べて事**なき**を**得よう**

what does なき mean here? Also what difference would it make if I replace 食べて事 with 食べ**る**事?

Comment: In some of your questions the Japanese sentences have unnecessary spaces between the characters. Could you please ensure that your sentences are well formatted? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[事]{こと}なきを[得]{え}る is a set phrase meaning 大事にならないで済む, "to escape a trouble" "to get something done without any trouble" "survive without a problem".

> 事なきを得る（ことなきをえる）
>   [大事]{だいじ}にならないで[済]{す}む。「出発時間に間に合って事なきを得た」
>   （from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8D%E3%82%92%E5%BE%97%E3%82%8B/)）

> ことなきをえる【事無きを得る】
>   「なんとか事無きをえた」
>   Somehow we 「finished it [got it finished] without any trouble.
>   「都合よく彼が現れて事無きを得た」
>   His timely arrival saved the day.
>   （from [プログレッシブ和英辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%BA%8B%E7%84%A1%E3%81%8D%E3%82%92%E5%BE%97%E3%82%8B/)）

---

Breakdown:

全員の -- "everyone's"
オススメ -- "recommendation"
を食べて -- "(I'll) eat and" / "by eating"
事なきを得よう -- volitional form of 事なきを得る. "I'll avoid getting into a trouble."

なき is the literary form of ない（無い）. It's the attributive form (連体形) of なし.

Comment: I would have expected a 体言 to follow the 連体形, but why does it connect to を here?

Comment: @Sweeper In 文語 (classical/literary Japanese), 連体形 can connect to case particles like を, が, に... eg 「 **古きを** [温]{たず}ね**新しきを**知る」, 「かぐや姫のやもめ**なるを** ...」